# Finding the characteristic curves for $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} -y\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> **problem** : Find the characteristic curves for pde $$ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} -y\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=0$$
>
> if 1)$y<0$
>
> 2)$y>0$
>
> 3)$y=0$
>
> 4)$y \neq 0$
>
> **Solution**:
>
> 1)Here characteristic curve is Ellipse
>
> 2) characteristic curve is hyperbola
>
> 3)characteristic curve is parabola

Am I doing right ?